# SQL query XML multiple nodes a columns

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have XML in a DB column with some other columns:

```
RowID    PeopleXML
1        <people>2 people nodes</people>
2        <people>3 people nodes</people>
```

Each XML column is structured like

```
<people>
    <person Name="Aaron" Lastname="Man"></person>   
    <person Name="Barbara" Lastname="Woman"></person>
</people>
```

There is not a fixed number of person nodes within people. There could be non or any given number of them.

I want to query using SQL Server. I need all the people for each data row in a single row. For example

```
RowID  name1  lastname1  name2    lastname2
1      Aaron  Man        Barbara  Woman
2      .....  ....       ....     .....     ...  ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(RowID INT IDENTITY,PeopleXML XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (N'<people type="many people">
        <person Name="Aaron" Lastname="Man"></person>   
        <person Name="Barbara" Lastname="Woman"></person>
    </people>')
,(N'<people type="one person">
        <person Name="Lonely" Lastname="Boy"></person>   
    </people>')
,(N'<people type="nobdy">
    </people>')
,(NULL);

SELECT RowID
      ,PeopleXML.value(N'(/people/@type)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS TypeDescription 
      ,pers.value(N'@Name',N'nvarchar(max)') AS PersonName
      ,pers.value(N'@Lastname',N'nvarchar(max)') AS PersonLastname
FROM @tbl
OUTER APPLY PeopleXML.nodes(N'/people/person') AS A(pers);
```

The result

```
RowID   TypeDescription PersonName  PersonLastname
1       many people     Aaron       Man
1       many people     Barbara     Woman
2       one person      Lonely      Boy
3       nobdy           NULL        NULL
4       NULL            NULL        NULL
```

Use `CROSS APPLY` if you want to reduce the result to rows with a `<Person>`.

### UPDATE: Pivoted

I just saw, that you need the result in one row... In most cases not the best you can do... Should be for output only...

```sql
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT RowID
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RowID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PersonIndex
          ,PeopleXML.value(N'(/people/@type)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS TypeDescription 
          ,pers.value(N'@Name',N'nvarchar(max)') AS PersonName
          ,pers.value(N'@Lastname',N'nvarchar(max)') AS PersonLastname
    FROM @tbl
    OUTER APPLY PeopleXML.nodes(N'/people/person') AS A(pers)
)
SELECT RowID
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN PersonIndex=1 THEN PersonName END) AS Nm1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN PersonIndex=1 THEN PersonLastname END) AS LNm1
      --second person
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN PersonIndex=2 THEN PersonName END) AS Nm2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN PersonIndex=2 THEN PersonLastname END) AS LNm2
      --add as many as you need
FROM Numbered 
GROUP BY RowID;
```

the result

```
    Nm1    LNm1     Nm2     LNm2
1   Aaron   Man     Barbara Woman
2   Lonely  Boy     NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try this and post the outcome.